# Table doesn't exist error in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

The issue is,

> a:5:{i:0;s:391:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 
>       Table 'mohchaii_mage828.mgmu_tag_summary' doesn't exist, query was:
>
> SELECT 
>       `tag_summary`.`popularity`, `tag`.* FROM `mgmu_tag_summary` AS `tag_summary`
>            INNER JOIN `mgmu_tag` AS `tag` ON tag.tag_id = tag_summary.tag_id AND 
>       tag.status = 1 WHERE (tag_summary.store_id = '1') AND (tag_summary.products
>        > 0) ORDER BY `popularity` DESC LIMIT 20";i:1;s:4257:"#0
>       /home/mohchaiinfusion/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what did you see on your website?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the Magento Admin.
Click System > Index Management.
Select the check box next to each type of indexer to change.
From the Actions list, click the indexing mode.
Click Submit. than working because this error is index management

Answer (score 0):

This type of error basically arises when you are trying to run a query on a table that doesn't exists. So first you need to see whether the particular table is there in the database or not. If it is present flush all the cache and try running all the reindexing.